# Why free() is not work, The previous value remains on the pointer

Tags: c

This is the code I made.

If you erase the free function, it works well, but if you use the free function, the previous value remains.

I printed out the dest value for the test.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *str)
{
    while (*dest)
    {
        dest++;
    }
    while (*str)
    {
        *dest = *str;
        dest++;
        str++;
    }
}
int get_str_len(char *str)
{
    int len;

    len = 0;
    while (*str)
    {
        len++;
        str++;
    }
    return (len);
}
#include <stdio.h>
char    *ft_strjoin(int size, char **strs, char *sep)
{
    char    *dest;
    int     len;
    int     i;

    if (size > 0)
        len = get_str_len(sep) * (size - 1);
    i = 0;
    while(i < size)
    {
        len += get_str_len(strs[i]);
        i++;
    }
    dest = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    printf("%s", dest);
    len = get_str_len(dest);
    if (dest == NULL)
    {
        dest = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
        *dest = '\0';
        return (dest);
    }
    i = 0;
    while(i < size)
    {
        ft_strcpy(dest, strs[i]);
        if (i != size - 1)
            ft_strcpy(dest, sep);
        i++;
    }
    return (dest);
}
```

This is main

The main function is for testing and there is nothing wrong with the part where I call up the code I wrote.

```
int     main(void)
{
    int     index;
    char    **strs;
    char    *separator;
    char    *result;

    strs = (char**)malloc(4 * sizeof(strs));
    strs[0] = "lol";
    strs[1] = "1234";
    strs[2] = "poiuic";
    strs[3] = "1234";
    separator = " ";
    index = 0;
    printf("=====REAL ANSWER=====\n");
    printf("result with size = 0 : $$\n");
    printf("result with size = 1 : $lol$\n");
    printf("result with size = 2 : $lol1234$\n");
    printf("result with size = 3 : $lol1234poiuic$\n");

    printf("=====YOUR ANSWER=====\n");
    index = 0;
    while (index < 4)
    {
        result = ft_strjoin(index, strs, separator);
        printf("result with size = %d : $%s$\n", index, result);
        index++;
        free(result);
    }
}
```

This is Result

```
=====REAL ANSWER=====
result with size = 0 : $$
result with size = 1 : $lol$
result with size = 2 : $lol1234$
result with size = 3 : $lol1234poiuic$
=====YOUR ANSWER=====
result with size = 0 : $$
result with size = 1 : $lol$
lolresult with size = 2 : $lollol 1234$
lollol 1234result with size = 3 : $lollol 1234lol 1234 poiuic$
```

Comment: *Aside:* `dest = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len); printf("%s", dest); len = get_str_len(dest);` is a big block of undefined behaviour since `dest` is not initialized. Also you only check if allocation fails after having attempted to use the memory twice already (and fail to check your next allocation). Additionally, you'd be overwriting `len`. The fact you get any output from this program is (un)lucky. Try compiling with [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The `free()` function does not change the value stored in your pointer variable, nor does it necessarily release the previously-allocated memory from valid use by your program.

It *does*, however, remove from you any guarantee that you have any right to it. Hence, using it after calling `free` is *undefined behavior*. (But will generally just get you an access violation and crash.)

Comment: Re “But will generally just get you an access violation and crash”: That is not a very likely outcome. Memory allocation routines do not generally unmap freed memory except maybe for huge allocations that were worth their own individual mappings. A more likely outcome is, when writing, corrupting data in use by other parts of the program (because the memory was reallocated for another purpose) or, when reading, getting bad data (because the memory contents have been changed). These can lead indirectly to access violations if pointers are affected.